# How to get a drag gesture when a drag event starts out of the stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How to detect drag events for the stack when drag action have started outside of the stack view?

On the screen are placed the main stack/view (GREEN) and sub-stack/view (RED). I need to implement functionality which detects swipe/drag interaction for the GREEN view. Here are two scenarios and the second is failing:

| FAILING | OK |
| --- | --- |
| When the drag gesture starts outside (on the GREEN view) of the RED view and then swiping over RED view onChange event for RED view can not be retrieved. | When the drag gesture starts on the RED view onChange events are retrieved and drag gesture can be tracked. |
| [image] | [image] |

How to detect drag events when drag have started outside of the stack view?

I have tried many things over the week. Some of them are:

- I have tried setting coordinate space for drag coordinates, and some views.
- Tried adding multiple simultaneous gesture recognizers.

Sample code which can be added to Xcode Playgrounds or demo app.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("3")
            }
            .id("RED")
            .frame(width: 200, height: 300, alignment: .center)
            .background(.red)
            .simultaneousGesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged({
                        print("", $0.location)
                    })
            )
        }
        .id("GREEN")
        .frame(width: 400, height: 700, alignment: .center)
        .background(.green)
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({
                    print("", $0.location)
                })
        )
    }
}

// Write grean rectangle 

let view =  DemoView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Comment: Can the location and/or sizes of the two views (red and green) change? What about their shape? Is it necessarily a rectangle? In case the answer to the first question is no and the answer to the second one is yes, you could consider keeping two interval trees, one for X and one for Y coordinates, and query both `onDragChange`. Counting the number of elements in the result should do the trick here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a **container** to have a same ***coordinate system*** for all views
2. Find *frame*s for all desired views in that **container**
3. Perform actions if the drag location is inside the desired *frame* in that ***coordinate system***

```swift
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var greenFrame: CGRect = .zero
    @State private var redFrame: CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                .background { GeometryReader { p in
                    Spacer().onAppear() { greenFrame = p.frame(in: .named("CONTAINER")) }
                }}
            Color.red
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .background { GeometryReader { p in
                    Spacer().onAppear { redFrame = p.frame(in: .named("CONTAINER")) }
                }}
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "CONTAINER")
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged {
                if redFrame.contains($0.location) { print("", $0.location) }
                if greenFrame.contains($0.location) { print("", $0.location) }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an overlay in this version it detects red drag [exclusively] if you start in red and green [also exclusively] if you start in green.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        DemoView()
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

struct DemoView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
    }
    .id("GREEN")
    .frame(width: 400, height: 700, alignment: .center)
    .background(.green)
    .simultaneousGesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged({
                print("", $0.location)
            })
    ).overlay {
        VStack {
            Text("3")
        }
        .id("RED")
        .frame(width: 200, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        .background(.red)
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({
                    print("", $0.location)
                })
        )
    }
  }
}
```

So if I comment out the green gesture and use the coordinates returned, I can use the coordinates returned to work out if I am in red or green within the "red" drag gesture.

```
          .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({
                    if $0.location.x < 0 ||
                        $0.location.y < 0 ||
                        $0.location.x > 200 ||
                        $0.location.y > 300 {
                        print("", $0.location)
                    } else {
                        print("", $0.location)
                    }
                })
        )
```

Of course, if you start within the green, nothing is reported. But start within the red, and you get both.

You can now uncomment the green gesture and use the same sort of logic, within its gesture.

```
    .simultaneousGesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged({
                if ($0.location.x < 300 && $0.location.x > 100) {
                    if ($0.location.y < 500 && $0.location.y > 200 ) {
                        print("", $0.location)
                    } else {
                        print("", $0.location)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("", $0.location)
                }
            })
    )
```

And there you have it; if you start on green it will work and if you start on red it will work.