# Swiftui tab bar not clickable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to achieve this type of tab bar. I have almost completed but Issue is its working fine on slide but its not clicking

[image]

My code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var currentTab: Tab = sampleTabs.first!
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ proxy in
            let screenSize = proxy.size
            
            ZStack (alignment: .top){
                Color(hex: "#E8ECF4")
                tabHeader(size: screenSize)
                TabView(selection: $currentTab){
                    ForEach(sampleTabs) {tab in
                        GeometryReader{ proxy in
                            VStack(alignment: .center){
                                matchCardView()
                                    .frame(width: 376)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        print("asd")
                                        
                                    }
                                
                            }
                            .padding(.top, 60)
                        }
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .offsetX{ value in
                            if currentTab == tab {
                                offset = value - (screenSize.width * CGFloat(indexOf(tab: tab)))
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(tab)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page (indexDisplayMode:.never))
                
            }
            .frame(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func tabHeader(size: CGSize)-> some View{
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            ForEach(sampleTabs){ tab in
                Text(tab.tabName)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .padding(.vertical, 6)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .leading){
            Capsule()
                .fill(.white)
                .overlay(alignment: .leading, content: {
                    GeometryReader{_ in
                        HStack(spacing: 0){
                            ForEach(sampleTabs){ tab in
                                Text(tab.tabName)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 6)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        print("asd")
                                        withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                                            currentTab = tab
                                        }
                                    }
                                
                                
                            }
                        }
                        .offset(x: -tabOffset(size: size, padding: 30))
                        
                    }
                    .frame(width: size.width - 30)
                })
                .frame(width: (size.width - 30) / CGFloat(sampleTabs.count))
                .mask({
                    Capsule()
                })
                .offset(x: tabOffset(size: size, padding: 30))
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(15)
        .background{
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.green)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    func tabOffset(size: CGSize, padding: CGFloat)-> CGFloat{
        return (-offset / size.width) * ((size.width - padding) / CGFloat(sampleTabs.count))
    }
    
    func indexOf(tab: Tab)-> Int{
        let index = sampleTabs.firstIndex { CTab in
            CTab == tab
        } ?? 0
        return index
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

In this all the things are working fine on slide but onTapGesture not working I try to print it something also But nothings works Maybe because of overlay or something.

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to implement a custom page control that moves between indicators by clicking on items or sliding the pages. Some thing like this:

[image: Demo]

So, I think of using the `matchedGeometryEffect` instead of all manual calculations

1. Define a `@Namespace` to store identities
2. Connect the `green` background to the namespace
3. Enable the animation based on the `selectedTab`

```
enum Tab: CaseIterable {
    case red, yellow, blue
    var title: String { String(describing: self).capitalized }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var animation //  1. Define a `@Namespace` to store identities
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .red

    func view(tab: Tab) -> some View {
        switch tab {
            case .red: return Color.red.ignoresSafeArea().id(tab)
            case .yellow: return Color.yellow.ignoresSafeArea().id(tab)
            case .blue: return Color.blue.ignoresSafeArea().id(tab)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            ForEach(Tab.allCases, id: \.self, content: view(tab:))
        }
        .overlay(
            HStack {
                ForEach(Tab.allCases, id: \.self) { tab in
                    Button { selectedTab = tab } label: { Text(String(describing: tab).capitalized).frame(maxWidth: .infinity) }
                        .foregroundColor(tab == selectedTab ? .white : .gray)
                        .fontWeight(tab == selectedTab ? .bold : .regular)
                        .padding()
                        .background {
                            if tab == selectedTab {
                                Capsule().fill(.green)
                                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "SELECTED", in: animation) //  2. Connect the `green` background to the namespace
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(4)
            .background(Capsule().fill(.white)).padding()
        )
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode:.never))
        .animation(.default, value: selectedTab) //  3. Enable the animation based on the `selectedTab`
    }
}
```

<sub>Also, you can checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592411/5623035) if you want to enable the dragging of the buttons and detect which tab to activate</sub>